# windows azure vm expose endpoints to internet

Tags: windows, azure, networking

I have an api running in a windows vm. I would like to know if is possible to expose the api's endpoints to internet? I'm new in Microsoft Azure and I have limited knowledge in networking

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is. All you need to do is assign a public ip to your VM:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/associate-public-ip-address-vm